# using discord.ext.commands, how would I make a bot send its own username? python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I don't understand how I could get my bot to send its own username. I was thinking something like this:

```
@commands.command
async def sendname(self,ctx):
    await ctx.send("I don't know what I would put here")
```

If anyone knows the solution to this please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `client.user` or `bot.user`[depends on how you defined the discord.Bot].

```
@commands.command
async def sendname(self,ctx):
    await ctx.send(client.user.name)
```